# Laravel Request IP Address: will Requests coming from VPNs show the same IP address or not?

Tags: laravel, http, header, ip, vpn

Currently I am developing an HTTP server and I am using the throttle (access limitation per minute) functionality of Laravel based on IP address.

However I am afraid that when a VPN and/or Proxy Server is used by different people the incoming request will show the same IP address. The rate limitation is included only to prevent dedicated DOS attacks and I don't want the user of my website to be blocked by rate limitation if they are using a VPN.

First of all, I don't have a solid understanding of how IP addresses are obtained and stored in the `Request` object. I assume it is included in the HTTP request header however I wasn't able to find it in Google Chrome's developer tool, "Network" tab. The developer tool only shows the destination address and not the source ip address in the "Request Header" session.

Next, I don't have a testing environment where I can test whether the IP address will be the same when sending by different machines using the same VPN, hence I have to ask the question here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> will Requests coming from VPNs show the same IP address or not?

Yes, it will show up as the same IP address as this is the whole purpose of using a VPN service, to change the user IP address.

However, if you want to detect if a user is using VPN there are third-party services to help you with that https://ipinfo.io/

Comment: My question is, "will requests coming from two people using the same VPN show the same IP address"?

Comment: Somehow I've misread your question. Updated my answer.